# Entity Framework 6 DbSet.Find efficiency

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two methods of finding an entity by its Id.  The first uses an IQueryable object to find the object by its Id using a lambda expression and the other uses the built in Entity Framework DbSet.Find() method.  I wrote a couple unit tests in Visual Studio to create speed benchmarks for both methods to determine which one is better to use.

The funny thing is that the method I wrote gets better results than the Entity Framework built in Find.  Does anyone know why?

Here is the code for the Entity Framework method:

```
public virtual T Find<T>(int id)
{
    return dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

Here is the code for my method:

```
public virtual T FindById<T>(int id)
{
    return dbContext.Set<T>().Where(x => x.IsActive).AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
}
```

And here is the time it took for each one of these with selecting a few records from the db:

[image: Benchmark Tests]

Here is my test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class EntityBenchmarks
{
    EdiDataStore target;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Start()
    {
        target = new EdiDataStore();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        target.Dispose();
    }

    //this method is only here because i want to make sure that the 
    //database context is loaded into memory so that we can compare 
    //Find and FindById on an even scale.  Without this method, the first 
    //time benchmark that runs is hit with the overhead of loading the model.
    [TestMethod]
    public void Control()
    {
        var entities = target.GetAgencies();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FindBenchmark()
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;

        for (int i = 9177; i <= 9187; i++)
        {
            var entity = target.Find<Spot>(i);
            isSuccess = isSuccess && entity != null;
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(isSuccess);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FindByIdBenchmark()
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;

        for (int i = 9177; i <= 9187; i++)
        {
            var entity = target.FindById<Spot>(i);
            isSuccess = isSuccess && entity != null;
        }

        Assert.IsTrue(isSuccess);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your benchmark is correct? What are the times if you call `FindByIdBenchmark` first?

Comment: Everything that @Pawel said in his answer plus that you also need to take the DB into consideration. Query plans and results can be cached on the DB so to see if anything there might be influencing your results. You might have to analyze the generated query if they are different. To do this you need to use sql profiler. Do not forget to flush sql servers cache when comparing.

Comment: See my original post for the edit to include my test class.  The order in which the two tests execute is not a factor because i have the control method to take the hit of loading the model.  Also, if you notice, both functions will be affected by setting up the DbContext the same way because of the TestInitialize and TestCleanup methods

Comment: Thank you, we needed to be sure. Since your tests run once with unique Ids, there is not real benefit of `Find`, contrary it might have overhead, but hmm, U would not expect it to be so big.Could you try settting `target.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` inside the `Start` method and check the timings?

Comment: It's funny that you mention AutoDetectChangesEnabled. Because it is already false.

Comment: Lol, then I give up:) +1 and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how you set up your test it is impossible even to try to answer the question. Can it be that `FindBenchmark` is run first and the time includes the cost of bootstrapping EF? EF does some quite heavy lifting on the first query that is not related to the actual query but to lazy initialization so you can't really just compare the first query to following queries. `Find` on the other hand first looks for the entity in the entities tracked by EF while `FindById` will always go to the database - again if you are using the same context and switch the order the results might be completely different because `FindById` will bring the entity and `Find` will not make the trip to the database.

Comment: My Test Class is attached to the post now, I have a control method that runs and takes the hit of loading the model.

Comment: I don't see any control method that loads the model. I see only  `target = new EdiDataStore();` but it does not for instance force creating the model, loading metadata, generating views etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with the performance test.

1. Pawel was correct in his answer that, the first time EF runs, there is a great deal of overhead that occurs.  The first EF query takes significantly longer than others.
2. You aren't testing the same query.  Find "Finds an entity with the given primary key values" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx).  I assume your IsActive flag is not part of the primary key, so the methods above will produce different SQL statements.  You cannot compare the performance of two methods using different SQL statements.

   example:  dbContext.Set().Find(id) would produce something like:

   SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE FooID = 123

   On the other hand, dbContext.Set().Where(f => f.IsActive).FirstOrDefault(f => f.FooID == id) would produce something like:

   SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE FooID = 123 AND IsActive = 1

   This in and of itself can produce wildly different results depending on what indexes SQL uses and what kind of execution plan SQL Server decides to build.  If you want to compare apples to apples you should be comparing:

   dbContext.Set().Find(123);

   vs.

   dbContext.Set().Single(f => f.FooID == 123)
3. Your FindByID is executing extraneous code.  You are performing a Where(...) and then calling AsQueryable() on the results of the Where, and then calling FirstOrDefault().  The IQueryable(T).Where() extension method already returns an IQueryable(T).  Calling AsQueryable() after that is unnecessary.

If you want to explicitly test the performance of different ways to retrieve the same data, then you need to make sure that the methods are doing the exact same thing.  The best way to ensure that is to run SQL profiler and make sure that the underlying SQL being generated is the same.  Otherwise all you are testing is whether or not SQL Server can generate two different database queries that take more or less time than one-another to execute, which is meaningless.

Also, do not call extraneous extension methods on queries.  In this case the AsQueryable was harmless, but calling the wrong extension method can also materialize the result set, bringing every entity back into memory and running another query against the in-memory collection.  This can have huge impacts on performance as well.

Comment: DVK and Pawel.  I had already taken EF Bootstrapping out of the equation because there is a Test Method in my code snippet called "Control()".  You will see that by running that first, that method will have the EF Bootstrapping and the other two will be comparing apples to apples.